# What is a 'Partial Column' in regards to a DataGridView?

Tags: .net

I'm writing a user control that does some filtering on a DataGridView and I need to keep track of the number of visible columns. The `DataGridView.DisplayedColumnCount()` method is what I believe I want to use, but it has a boolean arg named `includePartialColumns` that is described in IntelliSense as "true to include partial columns in the displayed column count; otherwise, false." I have checked every reference I can think of including SO and msdn, but I cannot find a definition for a partial column. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Paul Williams hit the nail on the head. Unfortunately it turns out that `DataGridView.DisplayedColumnCount()` returns only the columns that are visible to the user, which wouldn't include any columns that are not currently within the viewable area. This means that if you have 10 columns with property `Visible` set to `True` but only 7 of those columns fit inside the DataGridView viewable area (the other 3 are viewable only if the user uses the scrollbar) `DisplayedColumnCount(True)` would return the value `7` and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,c71cf792ecca0cf9), it appears that "partial columns" refers to columns that are not fully visible.  In other words, if some columns are shown that exceed the width of the grid, and one of the columns is only partially visible, then this flag controls when the column is counted as being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know it existed.